# Google experiments api - get reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-experiments

I am using Google analytics v3 api. 
I can insert, delete edit etc experiments to my analytics account.

The problem I am having is getting the result (report?) back from the experiment.

For example:
I have an experiment named "Test".
I now want to retrieve the current results from "Test", like
the conversion and how many of my visitors have been used for "Test".

I do not know what api-call to make, and can not find a proper guide. 
Any help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go though the [core reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference).  What you are doing now is going though the [managment api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/experiments)

With the core reporting api you are selecting the dimensions and metrics you want which are pritty much the same ones that are used in the report on the website.  Here is a link to the dimensions for  Experiments: [Dimensions & metrics Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=content_experiments)

Comment: I'm now going through the core reporting api.
Do i need to query both my experiments and then calculate the conversion rate or is there a query for that?

Example of my query parameters: 
max-results 50
dimensions ga:experimentId
start-date 2013-12-01
start-index 1
end-date 2014-03-10
ids ga:xxxxxxx
metrics ga:visits
segment gaid::-1


I found the [http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/] and it has helped a lot.